# Priority Operation with parenthesis for my calculator

Tags: c#, .net

In my calculator, I would like the notions of operation priorities with parentheses.

I did a unit test to try to solve the problem but I can not make it functional.

## UNIT TEST

```
[Test]
public void Parenthesis_Priority_Case()
{
    OperandBase operand = OperandFactory.Create("(1+2)*42");

    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<OperandMultiply>(operand);
    OperandMultiply multiply = (OperandMultiply)operand;
    AssertIsOperandValue(multiply.RightOperand, 42);
    AssertIsOperand<OperandAddition>(multiply.LeftOperand, 1, 2);
}
```

## OUTPUT FROM MY UNIT TEST

```
Expected: assignable from <CalculateLib.Operands.OperandMultiply>
But was:  <CalculateLib.Operands.OperandAddition>

    at
CalculateTest.OperandFactoryTests.When_Create_ 
Is_Called.Parenthesis_Priority_Case() in 
D:\GIT\Calculate\CalculateTest\OperandFactoryTests
\When_Create_Is_Called.cs:line 79
```

---

The code that follows is my factory :

```
public static class OperandFactory
{
    private static Regex parenthesisRegex = new Regex(@"\((?<content>.+)\)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static OperandBase Create(string input)
    {
        if (HasParenthesisToRemove(input))
        {
            return Create(GetOperationWithoutParenthesisString(input));
        }

        bool isValue = decimal.TryParse(input, out decimal outValue);
        if (isValue)
        {
            return new OperandValue
            {
                Value = outValue
            };
        }

        bool isAddition = input.Contains("+");
        if (isAddition)
        {
            string leftOperand = GetLeftOperandOfAdditionString(input);
            string rightOperand = GetRightOperandOfAdditionString(input);
            return new OperandAddition()
            {
                LeftOperand = Create(leftOperand),
                RightOperand = Create(rightOperand)
            };
        }

        bool isSubstract = input.Contains("-");
        if (isSubstract)
        {
            string leftOperand = GetLeftOperandOfSubstractString(input);
            string rightOperand = GetRightOperandOfSubstractString(input);
            return new OperandSubstract()
            {
                LeftOperand = Create(leftOperand),
                RightOperand = Create(rightOperand)
            };
        }

        bool isMultiply = input.Contains("*");
        if (isMultiply)
        {
            string leftOperand = GetLeftOperandOfMultiplyString(input);
            string rightOperand = GetRightOperandOfMultiplyString(input);
            return new OperandMultiply()
            {
                LeftOperand = Create(leftOperand),
                RightOperand = Create(rightOperand)
            };
        }

        bool isDivide = input.Contains("/");
        if (isDivide)
        {
            string leftOperand = GetLeftOperandOfDivideString(input);
            string rightOperand = GetRightOperandOfDivideString(input);
            return new OperandDivide()
            {
                LeftOperand = Create(leftOperand),
                RightOperand = Create(rightOperand)
            };
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static bool HasParenthesisToRemove(string input)
    {
        if (!IsStartAndEndWithParenthesis(input))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!HasValueInsideParenthesis(input))
        {
            return false;
        }

        string[] groups = GetGroups(input);

        return groups.Contains(input);
    }

    public static string[] GetGroups(string input)
    {
        const string pattern = @"(?=(\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!)|)\)))";
        IEnumerable<string> result = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
        return result.ToArray();
    }

    private static bool HasValueInsideParenthesis(string input)
    {
        if (!parenthesisRegex.IsMatch(input))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static bool IsStartAndEndWithParenthesis(string input)
    {
        if (!input.Contains("(") && !input.Contains(")"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static string GetLeftOperandOfDivideString(string input)
    {
        string[] inputString = input.Split('/');
        return inputString[0];
    }

    public static string GetRightOperandOfDivideString(string input)
    {
        return input.Substring(GetLeftOperandOfDivideString(input).Length + 1);
    }

    public static string GetLeftOperandOfMultiplyString(string input)
    {
        string[] inputString = input.Split('*');
        return inputString[0];
    }

    public static string GetRightOperandOfMultiplyString(string input)
    {
        return input.Substring(GetLeftOperandOfMultiplyString(input).Length + 1);
    }

    public static string GetLeftOperandOfSubstractString(string input)
    {
        string[] inputString = input.Split('-');
        return inputString[0];
    }

    public static string GetRightOperandOfSubstractString(string input)
    {
        return input.Substring(GetLeftOperandOfSubstractString(input).Length + 1);
    }

    public static string GetLeftOperandOfAdditionString(string input)
    {
        string[] inputString = input.Split('+');
        return inputString[0];
    }

    public static string GetRightOperandOfAdditionString(string input)
    {
        return input.Substring(GetLeftOperandOfAdditionString(input).Length + 1);
    }

    public static string GetOperationWithoutParenthesisString(string input)
    {
        var match = parenthesisRegex.Match(input);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return match.Groups["content"].Value;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I would like to know if you have any ideas or solutions to this problem?
If you wish to have additional code parts, do not hesitate to ask me

## EDIT

The problem is that the priorities are bad with the paretheses. I would like to know where the problem is coming from because I can not identify it.

Comment: You have a wonderful tool at your hands: the debugger. put a breakpoint on the first line of your method, launch the unit tests under the debugger, step through you code and see if everything is done as intended. That said: regex is not a perfect fit for such a task - if you want, have a look at recursive descent parsers.